# Error in postgres database : table is not created

Tags: django, postgresql, migrate

When I migrate my django application then in "Postgres" database "django_site" table is not created. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: please provide more details about your question.

Comment: I am migrating my django application. I use postgres database. When I use migrate command django creates some table automatically. It includes django_sessions,django_admin_log etc. django_site table should be created but this table is not created after migrating. Other tables are created properly.

Comment: by default django doesn't provide it's site framework. so to get django_site table created please refer this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the sites framework

To enable the sites framework, follow these steps:

```
Add 'django.contrib.sites' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.
```

Define a SITE_ID setting:

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

Run migrate.
your sites table will be created now.

source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/

Hope this helps.